# Permission to edit options per node

Tags: nodes, users

In a content type there are tabs at the bottom for publishing options, add menu item, url alias, comments, etc. You can set defaults/access to these options when you create the content type. But what if you want to give the superadmin access to these options but not a lower level admin? And do this on a per node basis?

For example, I don't want the lower level admin to change the URL alias, publishing settings, or the menu position on a top section node, ie xyz.com/about. But he can make a revision.

Comment: This would need to be on a per node basis, not on the content type / node type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Override Node Options](https://www.drupal.org/project/override_node_options) module looks like it would help you out. More details from the module's project page:

> The Override Node Options module allows permissions to be set to each field within the Authoring information and Publishing options field sets on the node form. It also allows selected field sets to be set as collapsed and / or collapsible.

Comment: That seems to work in the content type / node type, not on a per node basis. I only want to limit these options on certain nodes of the same content type.